# Can't clone git repo

Tags: macos, git, centos, clone

When I try to do a git clone with the following command:

```
git clone git@git.skycareehr.com:skycare/skycare.git skycare
```

I get the following error message:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /media/psf/Sites/skycare/.git/
fatal: Unable to create temporary file: Cannot allocate memory
fatal: index-pack failed
[root@centos Sites]# remote: Counting objects: 67251, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (24305/24305), done.
```

As you can see, the compressing goes to 100% but the repo doesn't actually get cloned.

I'm on a CentOS virtual machine on a Mac OSX host system and this command has worked before. I've installed a fresh version of `git` using the command `yum install git`, but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Running out of memory on the VM?

Comment: Edit: Yeah, it says that my VM has run out of memory. I think I can figure out how to allocate it more memory... I'll just do some googling. If I can't get it to work, I'll come back with follow-up questions. Thanks.

Comment: Even after reallocating the CentOS VM to 4GB of memory, I still get the same error when I try to clone the repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This occurred for us after a Parallels (9) update. Nothing seems to fix the issue short of a downgrade. We tried updating the parallels tools, changing the OS versio, starting with fresh VMs -- but nothing worked short of a downgrade.

Note that in our case, the issue only occurs when cloning on to the shared host filesystem (which we must be able to do). This fails after the update with Ubuntu versions 12.04 up to 13.10.

Sadly, Parallels has been astoundingly sloppy with the shared host FS. We may be forced back to virtual box at this rate.

One other possibility is to just set up an NFS export on your host and use that to share files rather than bothering with the shared filesystem. This seems to work ok for us. Here's a gist that shows how to set it uo:

https://gist.github.com/mowings/9782264

Comment: Yep, me too. Here's the upstream thread: http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?299965-9-0-24217

Answer (score 0):

Parallels has released an update which fixed this issue for me:

[Official Parallels Support Post](http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?299965-9-0-24217-update-breaks-git-clone-on-shared-FS-(Ubuntu-13-04-and-Ubuntu-13-10)&p=738313&viewfull=1#post738313)

Make sure you've got the latest Parallels Build: 9.0.24237. Instructions for updating Parallels can be found here: [How to get the latest build of Parallels Desktop for Mac](http://kb.parallels.com/111603).